# error when parsing yahoo weather xml in python

Tags: python, xml, django, ubuntu, yahoo-weather-api

I have been searching for a solution,  so i am trying to get weather information for a location id in my database,it is meant to use location_id from model and store the information in weather log a model in my database this is the code and the error below:

```
 ![# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
    import urllib
    from xml.dom import minidom
    from xml.dom.minidom import parse
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    from pprint import pprint
    from datetime import datetime

    from django.db import models
    from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand

    Location = models.get_model("weatherapp", "Location")
    WeatherLog = models.get_model("weatherapp", "WeatherLog")

    SILENT, NORMAL, VERBOSE = 0, 1, 2

    WEATHER_URL = 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=%s&u=c'
    METRIC_PARAMETER = ''
    WEATHER_NS = "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"

    def weather_for_location(location_id, options):
        # taken from http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-xml.html
        # and modified a little
        url = WEATHER_URL % location_id


        try:
            dom = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))
        except Exception:
            return None


     # Get the units of the current feed.
        yunits = dom.getElementsByTagNameNS(WEATHER_NS, 'units') \[0\]


        # Get the location of the specified location code.
        ylocation = dom.getElementsByTagNameNS(WEATHER_NS, 'location') \[0\]

        # Get the current conditions.
        ycondition = dom.getElementsByTagNameNS(WEATHER_NS, 'condition') \[0\]

        forecasts = \[\]
        for node in enumerate( dom.getElementsByTagNameNS(WEATHER_NS, 'forecast')):
               forecasts.append({
                    'date': node.getAttribute('date'),
                    'low': node.getAttribute('low'),
                    'high': node.getAttribute('high'),
                    'condition': node.getAttribute('text')
               })

        return {
            'current_condition': ycondition.getAttribute('text'),
            'current_temp': ycondition.getAttribute('temp'),
            'current_humidity': yatmosphere.getAttribute('humidity'),
            'current_visibility': yatmosphere.getAttribute('visibility'),
            'current_wind_speed': ywind.getAttribute('speed'),
            'forecasts': forecasts,
            'title': dom.getElementsByTagName('title')\[0\].firstChild.data,
            'guid': dom.getElementsByTagName('guid')\[0\].firstChild.data,
        }            

    class Command(NoArgsCommand):
        help = "Aggregates data from weather feed"
        def handle_noargs(self, **options):
            verbosity = int(options.get('verbosity', NORMAL))

            created_count = 0
            for l in Location.objects.all():
                weather = weather_for_location(l.location_id, options)
                if verbosity > NORMAL:
                    pprint(weather)
                timestamp_parts = map(int, weather\['guid'\].split("_")\[1:-1\])
                timestamp = datetime(*timestamp_parts)
                log, created = WeatherLog.objects.get_or_create(
                     location=l,
                     timestamp=timestamp,
                     defaults={
                        'temperature': weather\['current_temp'\],
                        'humidity': weather\['current_humidity'\],
                        'wind_speed': weather\['current_wind_speed'\],
                        'visibility': weather\['current_visibility'\],
                        }
                     )
                if created:
                    created_count += 1
            if verbosity > NORMAL:
                print "New weather logs: %d" % created_count][1]
```

error:

```
> File
> "/home/temi/rapidsmstuts/myapp/weatherapp/management/commands/check_weather.py",
> line 74, in handle_noargs
>     timestamp_parts = map(int, weather['guid'].split("_")[1:-1]) TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'


File "/home/temi/rapidsmstuts/myapp/weatherapp/management/commands/check_weather.py", line 47, in weather_for_location
    'date': node.getAttribute('date'),
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'




File "/home/temi/rapidsmstuts/myapp/weatherapp/management/commands/check_weather.py", line 35, in weather_for_location
    yunits = dom.getElementsByTagNameNS(WEATHER_NS, 'units') [0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That seems to be a **very** verbose way of doing it. You might want to check out `feedparser`.

Comment: @Matthew thanks i have never heard of it. please any ideas of how to use it in this code

Comment: The documentation is at https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/basic.html - I would start there

Comment: @MatthewDaly sorry just to go back to your first comment, please can you explain what you mean by very verbose way of doing it. thanks

Comment: It looks to me like you're having to write a lot of code to fetch and parse the XML, whereas feedparser will do that for you much more easily